# Can't deploy .net maui app from windows on physical ios device with HotRestart

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, maui

I want to use HotRestart with .net Maui. I programm on a windows 10 laptop and debug on an iPhone X.
I have an valid apple dev. account. When I start the debugging I get the following error:

2>Deploying 'xx.app' into the device 'iPhone von xxc'...
2>Deploy failed. The app 'xx.app' could not be deployed to the device 'iPhone von xx'. Please check the logs for more details. You can open Xamarin logs from the Help menu.
2>Deploy failed

What am I supposed to do?
If you need more informations just write a comment.
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Can a detailed error log be provided? Can you tell me the detailed steps of using HotRestart? It should be noted that if your developer account is a personal account, you need to [apply for Apple's API Key](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/creating_api_keys_for_app_store_connect_api). You can check the official documentation to check if your steps are wrong:[Deploy an iOS app using hot restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/hot-restart?view=net-maui-7.0).

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT it worked allready with the developer account. This issue is new and I don't know why. I didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you provide more error messages or error logs?

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT When I say continue building This is the output:
"Xamarin.iOS does not support running or debugging the previous built version of your project.  Please ensure your solution builds before running or debugging it."
I don't know where I can find more error informations. Error List is also empty.

Comment: Can you tell me your VS version number and your iPhone version number? You can also try to delete bin/obj folders from all the projects and cleaning and rebuilding the solution to see if it works.

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT I have iOS version 16.3 and VS-Preview 17.5.0 Preview 6.0. Deleting obj and bin folder and rebuild didn't help.

Comment: Your Apple developer account has been successfully linked to Visual Studio, and you have installed iTunes, right? You can report your problem to VS (in VS help->Send Feedback->Report a problem).>Send Feedback->Report a problem).

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT Ok thanks. I will report the issue.